# Display content from another web-site into AngularJs App

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, forms

Problem Question --

I have a Angular Application and I want to Display entire Form from my legacy web-form asp.net application. Is this something possible in Angular? Please note we don't have API for legacy code at the moment. In other words is there a way I can render a Form in a div in angularjs app? [image]

My thought so far.

1) Call the URL of the legacy application to display form.

2) Or not use Angular and just use JavaScript.

Please note this application need to send back to server as well. Any suggestion are welcome and much appreciated.

Comment: To me, you could use a html frame. Yes, is old fashion I know, but maybe is all you need.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your approach? Thanks

Comment: Is very simple with a frame you could load other page into your page. Check those links to view some examples: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: sorry, I have one more question - does this content(one displayed in iframe) can be submitted and send to database ? Thanks

Comment: It'll be submitted and sent to database using the old way. I'm assuming that you want reuse all (frontend/backend)